# What causes `Failure to read the spreadsheet` errors in BigQuery tables that are created from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a database table running which references a table created from a Google sheet. Sometimes this query runs whereas other times I see the errors

> Error while reading data, error message: Failed to read the spreadsheet. Errors: Deadline=118.95772243s

How I can make querying from this table more reliable?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [documentation for external data sources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#external_data_source_limitations), there can be some latency with Google Sheets since the data is not persisted to BigQuery, which is why the query runs inconsistently. As noted in the same documentation, it is recommended to perform the following options:

1) Store the Google Sheets CSV within [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=na-CA-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-dr-1007179&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_296784915985-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20%7C%20CA%20%7C%20en%20%7C%20EXA%20~%20Storage%20%26%20Database%20~%20Storage%20~%20Google%20Cloud%20Storage-KWID_43700037104291183-kwd-308056723381&utm_term=KW_google%20cloud%20storage-ST_Google%20Cloud%20Storage&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI17D1yf_u4wIVC_5kCh2iYg3yEAAYASAAEgKwx_D_BwE).

2) [Load the data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data)

Note: Loading data into BigQuery from Google Drive is currently not supported at this time, therefore step ‘1’ is required above for loading Google Sheets data into BigQuery..

In addition you may have the above steps scheduled  using [Google Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/). [Here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-transfer-bigquery-tables-between-locations-with-cloud-composer) is an example of how to use Cloud Composer to transfer from Google Cloud Storage into a BigQuery table.